# difficulty getting previous dates count from table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following tables:

```
table: users
id,
companyid,
name,
phone,
date
```

and

```
table: numbers
id
```

On table users I have 1 record as follow:

```
1, 22, 'John', '2123333223', '7/19/2015 10:02:19 AM'
```

and on table numbers I have this:

```
1,
2,
3,
etc.. until 30
```

I am trying to run a query joining both tables that will give me the following:

```
0, Jul 15
0, Jul 16
0, Jul 17
0, Jul 18
1, Jul 19
0, Jul 20
0, Jul 21
```

I have created the following query which I though it would give me what I wanted but something is odd:

```
SELECT 
        COUNT(v.id),
        date_format(x.dt, '%b %e') as cdate
  FROM (SELECT DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL (n.id - 1) DAY) AS dt
          FROM `numbers` n
         WHERE n.id <= 7 ) x
LEFT JOIN users v ON DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(v.date)) = DATE(x.dt)
AND v.companyid=22
 GROUP BY x.dt
 ORDER BY x.dt;
```

The above query give me this:

```
0, Jul 15
0, Jul 16
0, Jul 17
0, Jul 18
0, Jul 19
0, Jul 20
0, Jul 21
```

It doesn't count 1 record for Jul 19 as it should. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong. In the above example I hardcoded my date range to retrieve the last 7 days but ultimately I need to do something like this:

```
users.date between @from_date and @to_date;
```

as my stored procedure gets the date range dynamically. I am also trying to figure out how to include the between in my query. I read several different articles in stackoverflow and this is the closest I got to get it working. Any help will be greatly appreciate it thanks a lot.

Comment: does anyone know how to sort this problem? :(

Comment: still can't figure out :(